# Java Swing scroll JScrollPane by dragging

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

let's see if you can help me.
I have a jScrollPane with a jtable inside, and I would like to hide the scrollbar and make the user move around the table by dragging.
I found several answers in this forum about this topic but nothing seems to help me at all.
I would like to use as much netbeans gui as possible.
Thanks!

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me without any custom code:

```
JTable table = new JTable(100, 100);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
frame.add( scrollPane );
```

Comment: But also scrolling by dragging?

Comment: It will take you 2 minutes to try it!!! If it doesn't work, then you were asked to post your code!!!